# Adding Correct and Incorrect as attributes automatically to a Line layer in Mapinfo

Tags: mapinfo

I have a Polyline layer that I am adding to. Two of the columns are Correct and Incorrect. When I add a new Polyline I want these two columns to be filled out automatically with the Correct and Incorrect values.

Does anyone know how to done this using MAPINFO?

Comment: I think you would need to create a custom drawing tool with MapBasic in order to autopopulate any attribute information when drawing an object.

Comment: And the worst part is that i have a very limited knowledge of MapBasic. So, if you can suggest me some references (website or pre-developed code) then it would be very helpful for me. 

Well, thanks a lot Mr. T_Bacon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Default values are not existing in MapInfo, unless developed with MapBasic.

By the end of your work, you can populate the columns by using the "Update column" Function.